# What is the difference between DoFn.Setup and DoFn.StartBundle?

Tags: java, apache-beam

### What is the difference between these two annotations?

[`DoFn.Setup`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.Setup.html) Annotation for the method to use to prepare an instance for processing bundles of elements.

Uses the word "bundle", takes zero arguments.

[`DoFn.StartBundle`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.StartBundle.html) Annotation for the method to use to prepare an instance for processing a batch of elements.

Uses the word "batch", takes zero *or one* arguments ([`StartBundleContext`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.StartBundleContext.html), a way to access `PipelineOptions`).

### What I'm trying to do

I need to initialize a library within the DoFn instance, then use that library for every element in the "batch" or "bundle". I wouldn't normally split hairs with these two words, but in a pipeline, there might be some difference?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The lifecycle of a `DoFn` is as follows:

- `Setup`
- Repeatedly process bundles:

  - `StartBundle`
  - Repeated `ProcessElement`
  - `FinishBundle`
- `Teardown`

I.e. one instance of a DoFn can process many (zero or more) bundles, and within one bundle, it processes many (zero or more) elements.

Both `Setup`/`Teardown` and `StartBundle`/`FinishBundle` are optional - it is possible to implement any `DoFn` without using them, and with doing the work only in `ProcessElement`, however it will be inefficient. Both methods allow optimizations:

- Often one wants to batch work between elements, e.g. instead of doing an RPC per element, do an RPC for batches of N elements. `StartBundle`/`FinishBundle` tell you what are the allowed boundaries of batching: basically, you are not allowed to batch across `FinishBundle` - `FinishBundle` must force a flush of your batch (and `StartBundle` must initialize / reset the batch). This is the only common use of these methods that I'm aware of, but if you're interested in a more general or rigorous explanation - a bundle is a unit of fault tolerance, and the runner assumes that by the time `FinishBundle` returns, you have completely performed all the work (outputting elements or performing side effects) associated with all elements seen in this bundle; work must not "leak" between bundles.
- Often one wants to manage long-lived resources, e.g. network connections. You could do this in `StartBundle`/`FinishBundle`, but, unlike pending side effects or output, it is fine for such resources to persist between bundles. That's what `Setup` and `Teardown` are for.
- Also often one wants to perform costly initialization of a `DoFn`, e.g. parsing a config file etc. This is also best done in `Setup`.

More concisely:

- Manage resources and costly initialization in `Setup`/`Teardown`.
- Manage batching of work in `StartBundle`/`FinishBundle`.

(Managing resources in bundle methods is inefficient; managing batching in setup/teardown is plain incorrect and will lead to data loss)

The DoFn documentation was [recently updated](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/5b791489a5884cfd298578324ec08238d28f303c/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/DoFn.java#L486) to make this more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Is doing something in the Setup method different from doing it in the constructor or is just a matter of convention?

Comment: It is very different: if you do something in the constructor, it'll run once in the program that constructs the pipeline, before the DoFn is serialized and shipped to workers (which means e.g. you can't open connections in the constructor - a connection can not be serialized and shipped to a worker). If you do it in Setup, it will run once per DoFn instance on a worker - the constructor is *not* invoked on workers.

Comment: Basically, use the constructor only for trivially passing the configuration to the DoFn - e.g. assigning constructor arguments to member variables. Use Setup for anything else.

Comment: @jkff can you please share some examples how to use Setup/Teardown in Dataflow?

Comment: There's lots of examples of usage of either method in the Beam SDK, especially in IOs - just search for Setup, Teardown, StartBundle, FinishBundle within this directory https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/java/io

Comment: so `setup` gets called after constructor? can we use variable set in constructor further in `setup`?

Comment: Constructor is only called when you call it yourself in the main program that constructs the pipeline. From there on, the DoFn is serialized and then deserialized on each worker; deserialization doesn't invoke the constructor, it uses low level JVM machinery to create an empty instance of the class and restore the field values. But Beam will invoke Setup on each deserialized instance before using it.

Comment: @jkff **Summarizing:**
- `DoFn` constructor is called by user and pipeline is created.
- Beam _serialize_ the `DoFn` and send it to workers.
- When beam _de-serialize_ the _DoFn_, it calls `setup`.
- For each bundle it calls `startBundle` and `finishBundle`(all element of the bundle is over).
- For each element in a bundle `processElement` is called.
- `tearDown` is called --> no more bundle to process.

Comment: @jkff does the process of multiple bundles within the same `DoFn` instance might be done in parallel? Or is it always sequential?

Comment: @Daniel One DoFn instance processes bundles strictly sequentially - it won't be processing multiple bundles in parallel, and it won't be processing multiple elements within one bundle in parallel. See https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#user-code-thread-compatibility