# Apache Beam: ParDo and ML model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have trained a scikit-learn model (~70MB) which I want to use to make predictions with Apache Beam.

However, I am wondering if using `parDo` will load the model for each row, hence using an enormous amount of resources

```
class PredictClass(beam.DoFn):
  def process(self, row):
     call([...]) # copy the model from remote location
     model = joblib.load('model_path.pk1')
```

In my pipeline:

```
...    
predict_p = (query_dbs | 'PredictClasses' >> beam.ParDo(PredictClass())
...
```

Is there a better way to do it?
Where should I load the trained classifier?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load some resources for the usage of your whole `DoFn` you should use either `start_bundle` method of the `beam.DoFn` class (implement it and load your model there) or manually implement lazy initialization. This will allow you to load model **once*** and then use it when Apache Beam calls `process` method of your implementation.

******* it will be not exactly once, but you can reason about it in this way.

Here you have a great explanation with examples and some performance tests for initialization of re-usable and expensive to load objects in Apache Beam Python SDK [Apache Beam: DoFn.Setup equivalent in Python SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034374/apache-beam-dofn-setup-equivalent-in-python-sdk)

Comment: Setup and teardown have now been implemented in the Python SDK as well.