# One-time (per worker) setup for python dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My dataflow job has to download some file from remote server. I want to save the file on worker machine so job doesn't have to keep downloading the same file.

I tried to do this with `setup` method, however it seems `setup` will be called for each thread, and multiple threads can call `setup` in parallel (I cannot find documentation around this, but based on my experience my job tries to write file data in parallel and hence causing malformed data).

Is there a way to perform one-time setup whenever worker machine is launched?

I also checked [Apache Beam: DoFn.Setup equivalent in Python SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53034374/apache-beam-dofn-setup-equivalent-in-python-sdk) but I believe it focuses around per-thread setup.

Comment: I have one question, do you want to download this files before running the pipeline or after job start?

Comment: Before running pipeline.

Comment: Are you looking for `Shared`? https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.25.0/apache_beam.utils.shared.html

Comment: Shared indeed seems useful!

Answer (score 1):

The Beam model doesn't include a specific callback for when a VM is created because the model doesn't guarantee the runtime environment. However, because you are using Dataflow that uses containers you have two options:

- [Modify the container image](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/environments/)
- [Modify the setup.py](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/)

The first will give you direct control over the container image, and it works for all languages. The second only works for Python.

Comment: Just to confirm for custom image on dataflow I would have to use flex template right? https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/using-flex-templates
It has its own weirdness (I posted some other questions around this) and I didn't see success yet unfortunately