# Side inputs vs normal constructor parameters in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, broadcast, dataflow, data-processing

I have a general question on side inputs and broadcasting in the context of `Apache Beam`. Does any additional variables, lists, maps that are need for computation during `processElement`, need to be passed as side input? Is it ok if they are passed as normal constructor arguments for the `DoFn` ? For example, what if I have some fixed (not computed) values variables (constants, like start date, end date) that I want to make use of during the per element computation of `processElement`. Now, I can make singleton `PCollectionView`s out of each of those variables separately and pass them to the `DoFn` constructor as side input. However, instead of doing that, can I not just pass each of those constants as normal constructor arguments to the `DoFn`? Am I missing anything subtle here?

In terms of code, when should I do:

```java
public static class MyFilter extends DoFn<KV<String, Iterable<MyData>> {
  // these are singleton views
  private final PCollectionView<LocalDateTime> dateStartView;
  private final PCollectionView<LocalDateTime> dateEndView;

  public MyFilter(PCollectionView<LocalDateTime> dateStartView,
                       PCollectionView<LocalDateTime> dateEndView){

      this.dateStartView = dateStartView;
      this.dateEndView = dateEndView;
  }

  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception{
  // extract date values from the singleton views here and use them
```

As opposed to :

```java
public static class MyFilter extends DoFn<KV<String, Iterable<MyData>> {
  private final LocalDateTime dateStart;
  private final LocalDateTime dateEnd;

  public MyFilter(LocalDateTime dateStart,
                       LocalDateTime dateEnd){

    this.dateStart = dateStart;
    this.dateEnd = dateEnd;
  }

  @ProcessElement
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception{
  // use the passed in date values directly here
```

Notice that in these examples, `startDate` and `endDate` are fixed values and not the dynamic results of any previous computation of the pipeline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call something like `pipeline.apply(ParDo.of(new MyFilter(...))` the `DoFn` gets instantiated in the `main` program that you use to start the pipeline. It then gets serialized and passed to the runner for execution. Runner then decides where to execute it, e.g. on a fleet of a 100 VMs each of which will receive its own copy of the code and serialized data. If the member variables are serializable and you don't mutate them at execution time, it should be fine ([link](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/49403c00499f7f87c2bf9a4c63dec8ebd68d640d/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/WriteRename.java#L80), [link](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/b6cb4f44949603d1a1914dfd65b62d56ac403874/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BatchLoads.java#L327)), the `DoFn` will get deserialized on each node with all the fields populated, and will get executed as expected. However you don't control the number of instances or basically their lifecycle ([to some extent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985753/what-is-the-difference-between-dofn-setup-and-dofn-startbundle)), so [mutate them](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/49403c00499f7f87c2bf9a4c63dec8ebd68d640d/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/WriteTables.java#L158) at your own risk.

The benefit of `PCollections` and side inputs is that you are not limited to static values, so for couple of simple unmutable values you should be fine .

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't help me understand the OP's question.  I _think_ you are saying that, in his case, it makes _no difference_ whether the `startDate` and `endDate` are passed as side input singletons or directly as constructor arguments.  Do I understand you correctly?  If one method is preferred -- for static, pre-determined values -- which method is preferred?