# Are side inputs or constructor arguments preferred when DoFn arguments are static and pre-determined?

Tags: python, apache-beam

My question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57047359/side-inputs-vs-normal-constructor-parameters-in-apache-beam), but I want to understand it in terms of Python instead. (Also, that question does not have a definitive answer yet, IMHO.)

I have a `DoFn` to assist with loading JSON data (it populates the message with pub/sub info and manages fails by routing them to a different table). It starts like this:

#### Case A

```py
class JsonLoad(DoFn):
    def __init__(
        self,
        fail_tag: str = "fail", ### NOTICE THIS ARGUMENT HERE!!
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.fail_tag = fail_tag

    def process(
        self, element: str | bytes | PubsubMessage, error_timestamp=DoFn.TimestampParam
    ) -> Iterable[dict[str, Any]] | Iterable[pvalue.TaggedOutput]:
        if isinstance(element, PubsubMessage):
            for key, value in element.attributes.items():
                ### Then the work of adding pub/sub information and checking for errors...
```

But I could also write it like this:

#### Case B

```py
class JsonLoad(DoFn):
    def __init__(
        self,
    ):
        super().__init__()

    def process(
        self, element: str | bytes | PubsubMessage, fail_tag="fail", ### NOTICE THIS ARGUMENT HERE!!!
        error_timestamp=DoFn.TimestampParam
    ) -> Iterable[dict[str, Any]] | Iterable[pvalue.TaggedOutput]:
        if isinstance(element, PubsubMessage):
            for key, value in element.attributes.items():
                ### Then the work of adding pub/sub information and checking for errors...
```

Notice that `fail_tag` is moved from the class initialization into the `process` method.

The two are then called differently, by doing something like:

```py
  pipeline | "Make Data >> beam.Create(['{"test": "stuff"}'])
           | "Decode JSON Message" >> ParDo(JsonLoad("myfail"))
```

in **Case A** (by passing `fail_tag` to the `JsonLoad` object creation), or by

```py
  pipeline | "Make Data >> beam.Create(['{"test": "stuff"}'])
           | "Decode JSON Message" >> ParDo(JsonLoad(), "myfail")
```

where the `fail_tag` is passed as an additional argument to the `ParDo`, as in **Case B**.

---

They both work perfectly well, but I have **the following questions**:

1. If the argument is static and known before runtime, like in this case, which is "better" and why?

   - If they are identical, please also mention this.
2. If the argument is derived at runtime and potentially changing over time, which is better and why?
3. What else am I missing?  What is the purpose of choosing one method versus another?

   - I'm guessing there is some sort of mechanism wherein **Case A** is saving all arguments in its memory for each worker, and maybe the mechanisms of **Case B** do not. But I don't understand what's happening under-the-hood well enough.