# Apache beam DebeziumIO oracle Connector

Tags: apache-beam, debezium

Is it possible to use oracle Connector with DebeziumIO. I see in the KafkaConsumerFn, in the process method everytime we are creating jdbc connection. Will this work in high throughput envionment. DebeziumIO is still in expermental mode, when will it be moved to stable project

Answer (score 0):

A better place to create jdbc connections is under setup or start_bundle instead of in process, more details see: [What is the difference between DoFn.Setup and DoFn.StartBundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985753/what-is-the-difference-between-dofn-setup-and-dofn-startbundle).

About DebeziumIO, since Apache Beam is an OSS project, so maybe try contacting the main contributors to this [I/O](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/go/pkg/beam/io/xlang/debeziumio/debezium.go).